# activity life cycle with animation

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

I have four buttons calling different activities via intent.
the manner in which i am calling is something like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this,Test3.class);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

but i am unable to get it as expected..there is not animation i can see.
Am I calling animation start activity and finish in right way??

or rather I should use something like flag clear top?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)` directly after `startActivity(intent)`.

This should work for you:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this,Test3.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
finish();
```

Comment: yes i have done in that manner too.. but i am unable to get smooth animation.. it is not in the manner as i want.. Let me add one more thing this is i am doing in the resideMeu and using activities instead of fragments